# Regular expression range with decimal 0.1 to 1

Tags: javascript, regex, range

I' am using following regex:

```
/^(?:1|0?\.\d)$/
```

I need range between 0.1 and 1 with each number before and after dot. For example:

```
0.1 valid
1 valid
0.111 not valid
011.2 not valid
```

Valid numbers are [0.1-0.9] and 1

Comment: Is `.1` valid? How about `0.2`?

Comment: Yes 0.2 is valid

Comment: Replace `\d`  with `[1-9]`

Comment: `/^1$|^0(\.\d{1})?$/` (matches 0, 1 and 0.x) or `/^1$|^0\.\d{1}?$/` (matches 1 and 0.x)

Comment: @zana10 You never actually stated what your problem is/what's wrong with your current regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for the given test data:

```
(^|[^0-9])(0\.[1-9]|1\.0|1)($|[^0-9])
```

[regex101 example here](https://regex101.com/r/UitLFK/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
/^(?:1|0?\.[1-9])$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/TI7rcb/3)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0?                       '0' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

Bob's answer is along the right lines, however, it can do with some tweaking...

- So that it doesn't match `1. | .1`
- So that returned captures don't include `\n`
- So that the returned matches are a single dimension array

**RegEx**

```
(?<=^|[^[0-9]\.])(0\.[1-9]|1)(?=$|[^[0-9]\.])
(?<=                                            : Start of positive look behind
    ^                                           : Matches start of string
     |                                          : OR operator
      [^0-9\.]                                : Matches anything but 0-9 or literal "."
                )                               : End of look behind group
                 (                              : Start of capture group
                  0\.[1-9]                      : Matches 0.1 -> 0.9
                          |                     : OR operator
                           1                    : Matches 1 on it's own
                            )                   : End of capture group
                             (?=                : Start of positive look ahead
                                $               : Matches end of string
                                 |              : OR operator
                                  [^0-9\.]    : Matches anything BUT 0-9 or literal "."
                                            )   : End of look ahead
```

**Alternative style**

The range `0-9` can also be adjusted:

```
[0-9] == \d

(?<=^|[^\d\.])(0\.[1-9]|1)(?=$|[^\d\.])
```

**Flags**

You will also need to implement a couple of RegEx flags:

```
g    : Global
m    : Multiline mode
```

**JS Example**

```
var data = `
0.1    : Match
1      : Match
0.111  : No-match
011.2  : No-match
1.2    : No-match
0.2    : Match
0      : No-match
0.1    : Match
.1     : No-match
1.0    : Match
`;

var re = /(?<=^|[^\d\.])(0\.[1-9]|1)(?=$|[^\d\.])/gm;

console.log(data.match(re));  // Output: ["0.1", "1", "0.2", "0.1"]
```

Comment: Not to down play your answer.
Seems like 
^0\.[1-9]$|^1$|^1.0$ also cover all this pattern.

Comment: @Popeye You're right, it does __IF__ the string to be searched consists only of the expected data? e.g. `var input="1.0";` However, if it were to contain anything else then it doesn't match e.g. `var input="1.0 "` wouldn't match because of the space. It also wouldn't match multiple in one string e.g. `var input="0.1\n1.0"`?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm trying to modify this to not accept 1.0

Comment: @zana10 I've made a few changes to the above code... It should now match `0.1 - 0.9 & 1`. The regex above also now uses positive look ahead and look behind as I noticed that it was capturing white space in the output!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you ser! /^(?:0*(?:\.\d)?|1?|0.)$/gm; This works for me but accepts 0000 and a single 0, both shouldn't be accepted. Sorry, I forgot to say and trying to solve that.

Comment: @zana10 So... In your comment you specify `^` and `$`; therefore I'm now going to assume that there shouldn't be any other characters around the string. In which case you can use the middle part of the **RegEx** in my answer and surround with `^` and `$` **like:** `^(0\.[1-9]|1)$`